# How to fill entire height and width inside a Row Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I'm trying to achieve a Layout when all the children inside the Row Widget occupy the entire space, both horizontally and vertically.

```
class RowWithThreeChildren extends StatelessWidget {
    const RowWithThreeChildren({super. Key});

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
      return Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Flexible(
              flex: 2,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Text("One"),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 6,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: const Text("Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              flex: 2,
              child: LayoutBuilder(builder: (p0, p1) {
                return Container(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                  child: Text("Three"));
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      );
   }
}
```

The code renders this UI.

[image: Rendered code]

I want Red and Blue containers to expand the maximum available width and height of the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `IntrinsicHeight`(expensive), and using LayoutBuilder on top level to get the width.

```dart
class RowWithThreeChildren extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (_, p1) => IntrinsicHeight(
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: p1.maxWidth * .2,
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text("One"),
            ),
            Expanded(
              flex: 6,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: const Text(
                    "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."),
              ),
            ),
            Container(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              width: p1.maxWidth * .2,
              color: Colors.blue,
              child: Text("Three"),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This looks exactly what I want...  But the IntrinsicHeight looks hacky to be honest. Do you think is there another way of building this Layout as in native world this is pretty simple one.

Comment: well, we the row height depend on middle text height, we need to get the widget height and `IntrinsicHeight` is handy for this case. Or you can provide fixed height above row which you don't want i belive.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Expanded widget instead of Flexible.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, Expanded works only for the width, but not for the height

Comment: Text changes the Container's size. If you wrap the Text widget with a Center widget It should work as you expected.